# WPF: Focus is not transfered properly in Usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I create a user control and set **Focusable="True"**. This usercontrol have following buttons

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Name="btnPreviousClip" Focusable="True"  Template="{StaticResource controlButtonStart}"  Margin="2,2,2,4" Click="btnReverse_Click" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" KeyDown="btnPreviousClip_KeyDown" />
<Button Grid.Column="2" Name="btnReverse" Focusable="True"  Template="{StaticResource controlButtonReverse}"  Margin="2,2,2,4" Click="btnReverse_Click" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" KeyDown="btnReverse_KeyDown" />
<Button Grid.Column="3" Name="btnPlay" Focusable="True"  Template="{StaticResource controlButtonPlay}"  Click="btnPlay_Click" Margin="2,2,2,4" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyDown="btnPlay_KeyDown" />
<Button Grid.Column="3" Name="btnPause" Focusable="True"  Template="{StaticResource controlButtonPause}" Margin="2,2,2,4" Visibility="Hidden" Click="btnPause_Click" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3" KeyDown="btnPause_KeyDown" />
<Button Grid.Column="4" Name="btnForward" Focusable="True" Template="{StaticResource controlButtonForward}"  Margin="2,2,2,4" Click="btnForward_Click" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="4" KeyDown="btnForward_KeyDown" />
<Button Grid.Column="5" Name="btnNextClip" Focusable="True" Template="{StaticResource controlButtonEnd}"  Margin="2,2,2,4" Click="btnForward_Click" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="5" KeyDown="btnNextClip_KeyDown" />

<Button Grid.Column="7" Name="btnFav" Focusable="True" Template="{StaticResource controlButtonFav}"  Margin="2,2,2,4"  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="6" Click="btnFav_Click" KeyDown="btnFav_KeyDown" />
<Button Grid.Column="8" Name="btnResize" Focusable="True" Template="{StaticResource controlButtonResize}"  Margin="2,2,2,4" Click="btnResize_Click" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="7" KeyDown="btnResize_KeyDown" />
```

Also I wrote the got focus event of this usercontrol as follows

```
private void UserControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Keyboard.Focus(btnPlay);
        }
```

above code works well and focus is set to **btnplay**. but now if I press tab then focus is transfer to out of usercontrol(in place of **btnForward**) . I try a lot to find out problem and do lot of googling but no luck up till now.

Here i want to notify that once i press any button with space bar, then tab sequence(focus) works well.

Please suggest that where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried IsTabStop="False" for user control?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code of the ControlTemplates specified for the buttons, it is difficult to answer this question more thoroughly.

You should set the `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"` for the UserControl, and remove its `Focusable="True"`. This way, the TabIndex properties you have specified for the buttons inside the UserControl are only considered in the local scope, and focus will move away from the UserControl to the next suitable element inside the parent container once the button control with the highest Tabindex (btnResize) has been focused.

Please note that the `GotFocus` event is raised each time a focus change will occur. So having this event handler will effectively prevent you from switching focus inside the UserControl: once raised, focus is always reverted back to the Play-button. You should remove the event handler.